# looking for a regular expression to match specific decimal format in ng-pattern

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex, angularjs-ng-pattern

i am looking for a regular expression to put in ng-pattern attribute of angular.

i am looking for an expression that satisfies only a specific decimal pattern i.e.

```
exactly one digit --> than a decimal --> exactly 2 digits
```

i came up with

```
\d{1}\.{1}\d{2}?
```

The above pattern matches the following numbers correctly.

```
2.22
3.12
0.34
```

which is fine but if user enters `12.12` it doesn't reject this as I need it to.

Comment: You mentioned `exactly one digit --> than a decimal --> exactly 2 digits `, but you are trying to match `12.12` which has two digits before decimal ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want precisely this content and nothing else, you should use the start of word (`^`) and end of word (`$`) anchors.  Your regex would be:

```
var regex = /^\d\.\d{2}$/;         //then just bind to controller
```

[Tested on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/iV4pD8/2)

According to the [`ng-pattern` documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/input)

> If the expression evaluates to a RegExp object, then this is used directly. If the expression evaluates to a string, then it will be converted to a RegExp after wrapping it in `^` and `$` characters. For instance, `"abc"` will be converted to `new RegExp('^abc$')`.

Note that if you use a string input, you'll have to escape the backslashes to get the proper regex string.  In this case you could just use

```
<input ng-model="yourModel" ng-pattern="\\d\\.\\d{2}" >
```

Answer (score 1):

> exactly one digit --> than a decimal --> exactly 2 digits

Use word boundaries to prevent it to match unwanted text on either side:

```
\b\d\.\d{2}\b
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hR4iJ4/1)

Comment: this worked . ill accept the answer in 12 minutes. kindly if you could explain what do you mean by boundary. ?

Comment: I have added a regex demo that also has description of this regex. Basically `\b` (word boundary) asserts there is no word character before digit

Comment: @RaasMasood This will still match a string like `word 1.23 otherword`.  It will only match the 1.23 portion, but the input would pass the `ng-pattern` validation.  If that kind of string is acceptable, then this regex is the one to use.

Comment: this regex is wrong, you will have to use ^ and $ as "boundaries"
one counterexample would be 0.2.22 which would be accepted by your regex contradicting the definition